# Access javascript object created in a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, object

I'm making my first steps with javascript objects combined with php objects. So far everything is working fine, but I struggle to access the javascript object created in the ajax success response outside of this function.

Here is my JS code:

```
function settings(mannstage, stundenlohn, tags) {
    this.mannstage = mannstage;
    this.stundenlohn = stundenlohn;
    this.tags = tags;
}
var currentSettings;
SendAjaxJsonRequest("getSettings");

function SendAjaxJsonRequest(method, jsonObject) {
    jsonObject = (typeof jsonObject === "undefined") ? "none" : jsonObject;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "app/class/controller/ajax.php",
        data: {
            method: method,
            jsonObject: jsonObject
        },
        success: onSuccess
    })
};

function onSuccess(content) {

    var response = $.parseJSON(content);
    currentSettings = new settings(response.mannstage, response.stundenlohn, response.tags);
    console.log(currentSettings); //Returns the object
}
console.log(currentSettings); //This is undefined
```

The last console.log is undefined. How can I make `currentSettings`accessible outside the `onSuccess` function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentSettings` *is* accessible outside the `onSuccess` function, but your last `console.log` call runs immediately after `onSuccess` is defined, which is before it's been *called*, so the value of `currentSettings` is still `undefined` at that point.

Maybe editing your code like this will demonstrate it:

```
function onSuccess(content) {

    var response = $.parseJSON(content);
    currentSettings = new settings(response.mannstage, response.stundenlohn, response.tags);
    console.log(currentSettings); //Returns the object
    afterSuccess(); // Also returns the object
}

function afterSuccess() {
    console.log(currentSettings);
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about the asynchronicity of ajax. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sebsemillia: you're most welcome. The "A" is for asynchronous! (But then again the "X" is for "XML", so maybe the acronym isn't particularly relevant.)

Comment: Hehe, I know! But now I will remember.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is asynchronous, so the last console.log will be executed before the success function is called.